# Зачем ставится запятая?

Tags: запятые, глаголы

Почему в стихотворении Фета стоит запятая в первой строчке (после "приветом")?

Я пришел к тебе с приветом,
Рассказать, что солнце встало...

Это потому, что глаголы стоят не рядом? Ведь если было бы рядом, то не ставилась бы: "Я пришел рассказать..."

Comment: возможно, там было бы лучше двоеточие, потому что дальше несколько раз со слова рассказать начинаются конструкции: рассказать, что солнце встало..; рассказать, что лес проснулся.. Но, может быть, запятая оправдана концовкой, потому что песня всё еще зреет, поэтому лирический герой ничего не рассказал(все рассказав), а просто пришел с приветом. Я пришёл с приветом, (хотел бы) рассказать что-то - но только песня зреет..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Указанная запятая, конечно же, нужна.
В ее отсутствие предложение бы имело такой вид (да простит меня классик!):
*С приветом я пришел к тебе рассказать, что солнце встало...*

А ведь это совсем не тот смысл, который хотел передать автор. Если заменить существительное с предлогом ("с приветом") на глагол, то всё встает на свои места (но не звучит, правда?):
*Я пришел тебя поприветствовать, рассказать тебе, что солнце встало...*

Лирический герой влюблен, спешит на свидание ранним утром — он жаждет поделиться восхищением от рассвета и весеннего пробуждения природы, чувства переполняют его.

Вы обратили внимание, что всё стихотворение — это *одно* предложение, на едином дыхании? Герой торопится — *рассказать* (слово повторяется четыре раза).

Достаточно представить глагол "пришел" в начале второй строчки, и задумка "торопливого" поэта становится понятной:
*Я пришел к тебе с приветом,*
[пришел] *Рассказать, что солнце встало...*

[А. А. Фет. «Я пришел к тебе с приветом...»](https://ilibrary.ru/text/1322/p.1/index.html)

Comment: Спасибо! То есть можно сказать, что запятая обусловлена пропуском глагола? А как Вы считаете, если дальше идут 4 "рассказать" с точкой/запятой в конце каждой фразы, то не лучше ли (правильнее) вместо этой запятой выглядело бы тире?